# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar en pandas el tipo de variable para múltiples columnas?

Tags: python, pandas

Realizando trabajos en un dataframe me veo en la necesidad de cambiar el tipo de variable de objeto a float. El problema está en que mi df tiene muchas columnas y no sé como aplicarlo para todas ellas en una sola instrucción, por favor ¿me pueden guiar?

Para una columna uso lo siguiente:

```
df['columna1']=pd.to_numeric(df['columna1'],errors='coerce'
```

Comment: Probaste con recorrer cada columna del df con un bucle for?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer muy fácil con `apply` y `to_numeric`.

Utilizando un `dataframe` genérico como ejemplo, donde todos los valores son `string`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['1.0','2','3','3','4','5','5','6','7','8','9'],
    'B': ['1.0','2','3','3','4','5','5','6','7','8','9'],
    'C': ['1.0','2','3','3','4','5','5','6','7','8','9']
})

# Convertimos las columnas deseadas
cols = ['A', 'B']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Imprimimos el dataframe
print(df)

# Imprimimos la información
print(df.info())
```

Esto imprime:

```
      A    B    C
0   1.0  1.0  1.0
1   2.0  2.0    2
2   3.0  3.0    3
3   3.0  3.0    3
4   4.0  4.0    4
5   5.0  5.0    5
6   5.0  5.0    5
7   6.0  6.0    6
8   7.0  7.0    7
9   8.0  8.0    8
10  9.0  9.0    9
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       11 non-null     float64
 1   B       11 non-null     float64
 2   C       11 non-null     object 
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 392.0+ bytes
None
```

Y listo, las columnas deseadas cambiaron a `float64`.